# Local static object re-initialized in each new library or executable using mingw

Tags: c++, gcc, static, mingw, dynamic-linking

I've built a class factory that uses a local static object of a map to hold the names of all classes that it can create:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, ClassFactory*> typeMap;

static typeMap& getMap() {
    static typeMap map;
    return map;
}
```

Classes have to register to the map using this code:

```
DerivedRegistering(std::string const& s) {
    std::cout << "Inserting " << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Map size " << getMap().size() << std::endl;
    getMap().insert(std::make_pair(s, this));
}
```

If I want to create a new instance I call the static `createInstance` function of the class:

```
static Object* createInstance(std::string const& s) {
    std::cout << "Current map size " << getMap().size() << std::endl;
    typeMap::iterator it = getMap().find(s);
    if(it == getMap().end()) // not registered
        return 0;
    return it->second->create();
}
```

Let's say I have created this class factory in a header file of library A and I'm linking library A dynamically into a project that links another dynamic library B and creates an executable eventually.

Now with gcc under linux I have not experienced any problems with this, but when doing the same thing for Windows using mingw I get problems.

Output for gcc:

```
Registering classes of library B:
Inserting BA
Map size 0
Inserting BB
Map size 1
Inserting BC
Map size 2
Inserting BD
Map size 3
Inserting BE
Map size 4

Registering classes of library A:
Inserting AA
Map size 5
Inserting AB
Map size 6
Inserting AC
Map size 7
Inserting AD
Map size 8
Inserting AE
Map size 9
Inserting AF
Map size 10
Inserting AG
Map size 11

calling create instance in executable:
Current map size 12
```

However in mingw I get an output like this:

```
Registering classes of library B:
Inserting BA
Map size 0
Inserting BB
Map size 1
Inserting BC
Map size 2
Inserting BD
Map size 3
Inserting BE
Map size 4

Registering classes of library A:
Inserting AA
Map size 0
Inserting AB
Map size 1
Inserting AC
Map size 2
Inserting AD
Map size 3
Inserting AE
Map size 4
Inserting AF
Map size 5
Inserting AG
Map size 6

calling create instance in executable:
Current map size 0
```

So to me it seems mingw creates a new static local map for each library and executable while gcc uses the same memory for all of them.

The GCC behavior is the desired one as you might guess. Can I enforce this for mingw?

Comment: I don't think you can do this easily. Unlike shared libraries on Linux, Windows DLLs behave much more like separate processes - each has its own heap, for example, and also its own copy of static-storage-duration objects.

Comment: @Angew: Alright, that explains the behavior, thanks. I didn't know the behavior of dynamic libraries in linux and dll's in Windows is different like that.

Comment: It's really quite a painful difference. It also means that on Windows, you cannot `new` an object in one DLL (or the exe) and `delete` it in another, because of the separate heaps.

Comment: @Angew: that's only true if you deliberately fight to shoot yourself in the leg choosing unrecommended options. With proper ones you have a common heap and can delete away. Certainly the 3rd-party components keep the problem alive.

Comment: @BalogPal Wow, that's the first time I hear there's choice in this regard. Would you have a "more info" link handy, or shall I ask unclem Google?

Comment: @Angew: with just the RTL select the "shared DLL" versions. With MFC make your DLLs "MFC extension" or _EXTDLL type. All those will share a common heap. For one version.  Multiple heaps are created linking the static version of RTL, or using a mix of VC versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is static and included in multiple places. That means you get distinct bodies and distinct objects created.

Make the function extern in the .h and add a single body in a .cpp file, then you will have a singleton.

Alternatively you can make it inline instead of static for the same effect.

Comment: I have removed the static method and created an extern function as you suggested. This has worked out well.. After a full clean, rebuilding and testing everything, the behavior under Windows is now the same as under linux. Thanks a lot!